# Slew rate's effect on output waveform

Tags: slew-rate

I was asked to draw over the given graph in this question the output resulting from the SR.
[image]

Could it be something like this?
[image]

Comment: The op-amp output voltage cannot change faster than 1mV/us = 1V/ms no matter what

Comment: @G36 I understand that but how may I represent that datum graphically?

Comment: I mean how would it reflect in the graph of Vo(t)?

Comment: @G36 Would the output waveform therefore be triangular with slope equal to minus that of Vi? See attached graph above.

Comment: notice that at time 3ms Vi drops to 0V  http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/2.6%20Large%20Signal%20Operation%20of%20Op%20Amps/Slew%20Rate%20lecture.pdf

Comment: @G36 Better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first diagram represents an ideal differentiator circuit and you have made the SR correction by black, you have succeeded.